# Separate script tags from text in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say we have the following string:

```
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. 

<script src="http://foo.com/script.js"></script>

Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. 

<script>var x = 'a';</script>

Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
```

and I want to split it into an array that will read as follows:

```
[
  "Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.\n\n",
  "<script src="http://foo.com/script.js"></script>",
  "\n\nEtiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.\n\n",
  "<script>var x = 'a';</script>",
  "\n\nNulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.",
]
```

eg separate the script tags from normal tags and put them all in one array, how would I do that?

Comment: With ~2K rep you surely know you're expected to show an effort by now...

Comment: Based on your input you could simply split it on `\n{2}` or split on `\n` and use `filter(String)` to remove empties.

Comment: Sorry, I was just stuck

Comment: @Lukas what if you have a variable in your regex that contains `</script>` inside the value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it:

```
const embedCode = "...text from above"
const r = /(<script.*?<\/script>)/
console.log(embed.split(r));
```